# How can I avoid an encoding conflict when merging files in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, encoding, tfs

We are working on a large codebase in Visual Studio 2010 using TFS as version control system.

When performing merges we recently get a lot of encoding issues. For the most of them we get an option "Choose encoding and merge" for other files we get:

`"The encodings for the files being merged must match or an encoding conversion must be specified."`

We normally put every file in UTF-8, although we get conflicts when merging between codepage 1252 and utf-8.

To solve these issues we always perform a manual merge which can be quite cumbersome. How can we avoid these errors? What is the recommended encoding for source-code files in TFS? How can we recursively set the encoding to avoid errors like these in the future?

Answer (score 4):

You are getting the message because TFS thinks (correctly or incorrectly) that a file has different encodings in different branches. To double-check the encoding, go to the [properties window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.TFC.SOURCECONTROL.DIALOGFILEFOLDERPROPERTIES%29&rd=true) of any source-controlled file.

Although TFS detects the encoding when a file is added to source control, if the encoding is later changed TFS will not always pick it up. Click the [Set Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245453%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) button and then click Detect to see what the actual encoding is. If it isn't what you expect, then check out the file, modify the encoding in a text editor, and then have TFS re-detect the encoding.

Once the encoding is the same in both branches you shouldn't get this error any longer.

Comment: Is there a way to change encodings of files for an entire branch?

Comment: You could try using PowerShell or another tool to [change the encoding in batch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681568/change-files-encoding-recursively-on-windows) on your local filesystem. Then you could use the [`tf checkout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.TFC.SOURCECONTROL.COMMANDCHECKOUT)&rd=true) command-line tool to change the encoding in TFS:  `tf checkout /type:text /recursive .`. Not sure if that will work but it should give you a starting point.