# How to stop git from breaking encoding on checkout

Tags: c#, git, encoding, gitattributes

I recently added a .gitattributes file to a c# repository with the following settings:

```
*            text=auto
*.cs         text diff=csharp
```

I renormalized the repository [following these instructions from github](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) and it seemed to work OK.

The problem I have is when I checkout some files (not all of them) I see lots of weird characters mixed in with the actual code. It seems to happen when git runs the files through the `lf->crlf` conversion specified by the .gitattributes file above.

According to Notepad++ the files that get messed up are using `UCS-2 Little Endian` or `UCS-2 Big Endian` encoding. The files that seem to work OK are either `ANSI` or `UTF-8` encoded.

For reference my git version is `1.8.0.msysgit.0` and my OS is Windows 8.

Any ideas how I can fix this? Would changing the encoding of the files be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if you use an encoding where every character is two bytes.
CRLF would then be encoded as `\0\r\0\n`.

Git thinks it's a single-byte encoding, so it turns that into `\0\r\0\r\n`.
This makes the next line one byte off, causing every other line be full of Chinese.  (because the `\0` becomes the low-order byte rather than the high-order byte)

You can convert files to UTF8 using this LINQPad script:

```
const string path = @"C:\...";
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (!new [] { ".html", ".js"}.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file)))
        continue;
    File.WriteAllText(file, String.Join("\r\n", File.ReadAllLines(file)), new UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: true));
    file.Dump();
}
```

This will not fix broken files; you can fix the files by replacing `\r\n` with `\n` in a hex editor.  I don't have a LINQPad script for that.  (since there's no simple `Replace()` method for `byte[]`s)

Comment: I used your suggestions, but ran the powershell script from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681568/change-files-encoding-recursively-on-windows It seems to have fixed the problems.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, either convert the encoding of the files (UTF-8 should be ok) or disable the line break auto conversion (`git config core.autocrlf false` and .gitattributes stuff you have).