# Have Vim fully support UTF-8 on Windows

Tags: vim, utf-8

I use `vim` and `gVim` on Windows, and `vim` in a virtual Linux box for programming.  Often I need to change `gettext` catalog files.  However, the support for Unicode characters seems to be incomplete in both Windows versions, perhaps because of the character set.

For example, umlauts (`äöü`) work just fine; but typographical quotes („“ or “ˮ) and some other characters like mdash and ellipse don't (they **do** in the Linux box).  Vim complains about conversion errors and opens the files in read-only mode; when overriding this and storing anyway, those characters are broken.

Other Windows programs support those characters just fine, e.g. TortoiseSVN.

Note that this is not a “wrong encodingˮ matter, like `latin-1` instead of `utf-8`, as this would affect the umlauts as well. I'm aware of the settings `enc`, `fenc`, `fencs`, and of `:e ++enc=utf-8`.

`:version` tells me: version 7.3, MS Windows 32 bit GUI version w/OLE support, including corrections 1-46; `+multi_byte_ime/dyn`.

**Update**: Updating to Vim 7.4 didn't solve the problem. `+multi_byte_ime/dyn` and, since the options are listed more readably now: `+digraphs`,  `-xfontset`, `-postscript` (I don't know whether or not they are of interest).

Since I work on the same files with Linux Vim (still 7.3, including corrections 1-547) and, via Samba, the now updated Windows gVim, I tried the following: I opened a catalog file with the Linux version, which used to do the funny quote chars alright (`:set enc? fenc?` → `encoding=utf-8`, `fileencoding=utf-8`) and saved it to be Latin-1 (`:set fenc=latin-1` (File is marked changed), updated the markers, `:w`).  I got a conversion error; however, some changes had been written.

When re-opening the file with the same Linux version, I got correct umlauts, `encoding=utf-8` / `fileencoding=latin-1`, but incorrect quote chars.

Comment: What's your `'encoding'` setting? With `utf-8` (and the file in the same format), there should be no reason for convertion and therefore no such errors.

Comment: My files are saved `utf-8`-encoded, especially the gettext catalogs (`.po`). For these, the encoding is contained in a "Content-Type" header (and used for compilation to `.mo` files, I expect) as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading the question [How to view UTF-8 Characters in VIM or Gvim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5166652/1051649), I tried several `guifont`-settings (`:set guifont?` yielded nothing), and indeed some of them feature typographical quotes.

The following `guifont` settings worked for me on my Windows 8.1 system:

- Lucida_Console
- DejaVu_Sans_Mono
- Courier_New
- Consolas

For `guifontwide` I found

- MS_Mincho

to work for chinese characters.

Comment: As the author of this answer I'd like to make clear that I didn't add the `guifontwide` and `MS_Mincho` information; I don't have any experience with multi-byte character sets. This should have been a (likely useful, for a certain audience) comment, not an edit.

Comment: More generally, you can try fonts on your own system with the methods described at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Setting_the_font_in_the_GUI.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have been able to consistently change file-encoding to UTF-8 on windows is by using notepad++ or powershell (see below). Regardless of the VIM version changing the file encoding from within VIM is gives inconsistent results at best.

Once the file has UTF-8 encoding set outside of vim there are no further issues. File encoding set through vim on linux or mac are respected by windows.

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681568/change-files-encoding-recursively-on-windows) of powershell command is suggested to change the encoding. That is the fastest way I know of to set a project to UTF-8 on windowws and work without further hassle.

In your examples above, not that there is a difference between `:set encoding=utf-8` (which is temporary and only in your display) and `set fileencoding=utf-8` which will change the file on save.

Comment: As I tried to make clear from the beginning: This is **not** about using `utf-8` instead of `latin-1`.  This is about `utf-8` working for umlauts, but not for _(only slightly)_ more funny characters like quotes, dashes and ellipses.